# Is the square root of a matrix unique?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

I know the answer is No, since you can put plus/minus on each eigenvalue. But how about putting a psd requirement? Like $A = S^2$, $S$ is psd, is $S$ unique?

I was worried about the case where if $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2$, then we can flip the first two columns of unitary matrix $P$. You can require all eigen values distinct. But even if has same eigen values, the matrix shall be the same?

Comment: Are you assuming that $A$ is PSD? Otherwise you can't find  a PSD square root. If so, then yes, there is a unique PSD square root.

Comment: PSD = positive semi-definite, for those like me who need to google to decipher the abbreviations (possibly standard in English-speaking education, not mine)

Comment: Answer  first the easier problem: how may psd square roots does  the identity matrix have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A positive semidefinite matrix has a unique PSD square root - Horn&Johnson Theorem 7.2.6. Much more is know, see, for example,

*Johnson, Charles R.; Okubo, Kazuyoshi; Reams, Robert*, [**Uniqueness of matrix square roots and an application**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0024-3795(00)00243-3), Linear Algebra Appl. 323, No.1-3, 51-60 (2001). [ZBL0976.15009](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0976.15009). (available for free on line)